# Is it possible to change the prompt of Scala REPL programatically?

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

I want to change the prompt of Scala REPL. I found out that I can change the prompt in power-mode like the following.

```
scala> 

scala> :power
** Power User mode enabled - BEEP WHIR GYVE **
** :phase has been set to 'typer'.          **
** scala.tools.nsc._ has been imported      **
** global._, definitions._ also imported    **
** Try  :help, :vals, power.<tab>           **

scala> repl.setPrompt("\ncool prompt!> ")

cool prompt!>
```

Now I want to do this in normal mode or `initialCommands` of sbt console. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: FYI http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Howto/interactive.html#prompt

Comment: Thanks, but what I want to change is the prompt of Scala REPL and not the prompt of sbt interactive shell.

Comment: @totoshi sorry, I've misunderstood your question in sbt console part.

Answer (score 8):

Scala 2.10.0

```scala
$intp.asInstanceOf[scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$ILoopInterpreter]
     .getClass
     .getDeclaredField("$outer").get($intp)
     .asInstanceOf[scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop]
     .setPrompt("\ncool prompt!> ")
```

Comment: This code works well after REPL starts, but can't be compiled when I add it to initialCommands of sbt console. The $intp value can't be seen before REPL fully starts up. Is there another way to access the $intp value?